# Ruby Convert String to Decimal

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I convert `"$ 10.80"` to decimal? By using regex?

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal"? An arbitrary precision floating-point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's maybe not the best way to do it but here is something that works :

```
"$ 10.80".match(/[0-9|\.]+/)[0].to_f
```

Comment: Nice solution. Could just use this to extract the decimal value from any string. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
s = "$ 10.80"
BigDecimal.new s.match(/(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]
```

Returns your value as an [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to preserve precision.

Comment: Why not use BigDecimal if you want to preserve precision?

Answer (score 4):

There are already several solutions, but I'd like to add

```
>> "$ 10.80"[/[\d\.]+/].to_f #=> 10.8
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know that it always has `$` at the beginning, then just remove that, and a simple `to_f` will do.

> "$ 10.00"[1..-1].to_f

Comment: This.  Why would you complicate the problem any more than necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Code that may be easier to understand for regex illiterates:

```
"$ 10.80".split(' ')[1].to_f
```

Answer (score 1):

This soluiton matches any floating point number (including eg "$ .89") and preserves precision:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

s = "$ 10.80"

puts BigDecimal.new(s.match(/\d*\.?\d+/)[0]).to_s('F')  # 10.8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use split method.

```
"$ 10.80".split(' ')[1].to_f
```